# How to colorize an image in CSS?

Tags: image, css, colors

Is there a cross-browser way to use CSS to change the shade of an image. For example, if I have a grayscale icon (an `img` element), I'd like it to change the colors to sepia on hover.

It would have to work on browsers other than IE, so I can't use filter. Is there some CSS 3 trick that would allow that?

Comment: Nothing that I know of. Good question though. +1

Comment: Most likely not possible with CSS.. but you can do it with some Javascript and `<canvas>`

Comment: don't think it can be done css only. you might want to try a js library like paintbrushjs http://mezzoblue.github.com/PaintbrushJS/demo/index.html or pixastic http://www.pixastic.com/lib/

Comment: I don't think it's possible with css, you can use HTML5 `canvas` element

Comment: Have a look at this page. Maybe useful. http://www.w3.org/Graphics/fx/wiki/CSS_Image_Transitions

Comment: Check this jQuery library http://www.netzgesta.de/instant/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [css filter to make elements one color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999597/css-filter-to-make-elements-one-color)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update many years later: yes, you can colorize an image in CSS

I've asked for this question to be closed since it's a duplicate, but that probably won't happen because it's very old. Anyway, the currently accepted:

> "if you want to modify an image in css, it isn't possible to do that."

from the other answer was correct at the time, but has been incorrect for many years now.

[CSS Filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) allow you to do this.

From [css filter to make elements one color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999597/css-filter-to-make-elements-one-color) :

```
filter: grayscale(100%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(90deg);
```

There's an [online tool to generate the filters necessary to color an image](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp).

Comment: I can't even remember why I originally needed this, wow twelve years ago, but knowing that it's now possible makes me glad. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

if you want to modify an image in css, it isn't possible to do that. but you can play with the opacity property. yeah that only set the image opacity, but it will be a nice effect. here is an example :

```
img{-webkit-transition:opacity .3s ease-in-out;}
img:hover{opacity:.6}
```

that snippet will give a nice transition effect of fade-in and out image into transparent.

in other case, you can use image sprite to do what you want :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no *accurate* way to do this in CSS, as mentioned already you can utilize other technologies to do so - namely Javascript.

In the *very basic* sense, you could attempt to mimic a sepia style by overlaying a div on top of an image with a sepia *like* color and an opacity `rgba(94, 38, 18, 0.2)` - but this method is rather crude. You could even overlay using a transparent image, which might be better than this option (but still pretty rubbish).

Answer (score 1):

There is no cross-browser standardized syntax for this that I know of. You can, however, use HTML5 Canvas and do this effect yourself. Using `SVG` may also work, but I'm not sure about how well all browsers, in particular internet exploder, support `SVG`.

SVG example using a color matrix transform:
http://www.dhmedia.com.au/sites/default/files/examples/SVG-filters/sepia.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm really late for answering this topic, but I've been wanting to do the same thing as you and could not find an answer. But the first guy here gave me a enlightenment.

What I needed: An image that was fairly colorized by some color and when I hover it, it would be normal again. So what did I do, I set the background color to the color I wanted the image to be and then I reduced its opacity. So I got the colorized image. And when I hover it, I set background to be transparent again and image in its full opacity. So it's kinda possible to color an image usign backgorund-color and opacity with CSS.

```
img {
    background-color: rgba(122, 122, 122, 1);
    opacity: 0.5;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

img:hover {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

It worked nicely for me.