# css filter to make elements one color

Tags: css, colors, css-filters

The following CSS filter:

```
filter: brightness(0) invert(1);
```

makes elements all-white ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24224112/css-filter-make-color-image-with-transparency-white)). Neat, but is there a way to make them another color instead, e.g. blue? This is for situations where there is a transparent background, e.g. an icon. I want to make the icon one arbitrary color.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an **[online CSS generator to convert to a target color](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp)**.

For example, if you enter `#CC0000` it will give you:

```
filter: invert(8%) sepia(97%) saturate(7488%) hue-rotate(12deg) brightness(92%) contrast(114%);
```

It will also score the result for accuracy. You can keep trying until you get a perfect score.

I believe it assumes your image is black. If its not, to turn the image black first prepend this:

```
brightness(0) saturate(100%)
```

So using the earlier example the final solution (if your image is not black) would be:

```
filter: brightness(0) saturate(100%) invert(8%) sepia(97%) saturate(7488%) hue-rotate(12deg) brightness(92%) contrast(114%);
```

Now if only someone would write an npm package to do this for you dynamically!

Answer (score 24):

The `hue-rotate()` filter affects all colors however so it won't turn a full color image into a one color image. Rather it will move all the colors around the color wheel.

**However you can hack a solution by converting to grayscale, adding sepia and then rotating the hue** This make an image look like a single hue shaded green:

```
filter: grayscale(100%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(90deg);
```

If you care dealing with vector work like an icon that you will use a lot, you might consider converting it to SVG, then you can color it with plain css. https://icomoon.io can help with this.

Comment: Ah the `sepia(100%)` was great to get a white image to have color by reducing `brightness(0.9)` and then applying sepia, the there is a hue for rotating.

Comment: Why the W3C added something as niche as sepia but not something as mathematically trivial and versatile as a color filter eludes me.

Answer (score 12):

If you reference an SVG filter from your CSS, then you can get a specific color. SVG filter snippet below. For your specific color replace the .7/.4/.5 with the unitized value of your RGB values.

```
<filter id="colorme" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
  <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values="0 0 0 0 .7  0 0 0 0 .4  0 0 0 0 .5  0 0 0 1 0"/>
</filter>
```

hue-rotate() is a very impaired filter since it doesn't operate in HSL space. It's an RGB approximation which tends to clip saturated colors badly.

Comment: This works. And you can get approximate `feColorMatrix` color values from RGB here: http://andresgalante.com/RGBAtoFeColorMatrix/

Comment: I didn't know how to reference the SVG filter, this codepen showed a way: https://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/JdXpPB

Comment: https://fecolormatrix.com/ also does a nice job and shows a clear code example.

Answer (score 11):

Adding `contrast(0)` as the first step will flatten the icon's colors to a uniform gray, which I needed for my purposes. I also needed to fiddle with `brightness` and `saturate` to hit my target color.

```
filter: contrast(0) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(116deg) brightness(1.4) saturate(0.28);
```

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/paulcham/pen/QKbpLb)