# Transform PNG image to solid color with CSS or JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, colors

For a portfolio website I'm making with vanilla HTML, CSS and JS with Jquery I want to have a list of images with the avatars of everyone in my group.
However I want to implement an effect where normally the avatar image is replaced by a solid color silhouette of it(image 1), and then when you hover on the image it fades back to it's original colors (image 2).

image 1:
[image: Avatar Image when not hovering in solid color]
(solid color silouhette)

---

image 2:
[image: Avatar Image when hovering]
(original image)

---

For now I've achieved this effect by overlaying 2 images on top of each other. With the top one being the colored silhouette and the bottom one the original image. And then simply using the `:hover` selector in CSS to fade out the top image and reveal the one below.

```html
<div class="mb-player">
    <img src="../Assets/Players/Test/Test_color.png" class="mb-player-color">
    <img src="../Assets/Players/Test/Test_normal.png">
</div>
```

```css
.mb-player {
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    width: fit-content;
}

.mb-player img {
    object-fit: cover;
    height: 300px;
}

.mb-player-color {
    z-index: 1;
    transition: 0.3s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0; 
}

.mb-player:hover .mb-player-color{
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.1s;
}
```

However this means that for every avatar I add I'll need to have 2 pictures, meaning that I'll end up using a lot of memory and possibly degrading the performance on lower end devices.

Therefore I was wondering if there was another solution that used code instead to alter the original image and transform it to a solid color version of itself (as shown in image 1).
I've tried looking into CSS color filters, but those only apply a mild color change and don't make the solid color effect like I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28036807/2518285), it’s possible to get pretty close.

The first filter to apply is `contrast(0)`, which flattens the image to a solid grey. Then you can use `sepia(100%)` to add some color (a desaturated yellowish brown). Your next filter would be `saturate(1000%)` to boost the saturation back to something approaching full saturation. Finally you add `hue-rotate(320deg)` to go from yellow most of the way around the color wheel to red.

You can play around with combinations of `saturate()`, `brightness()` and `hue-rotate()` to find colors you like. I don’t know of a method for achieving a specific color, though, so it’s a process of trial-and-error, although the generator mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67615509/2518285) might help, or the suggestions contained in the other answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27999597/2518285).

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}

img:nth-child(1) {
  filter: contrast(0);
}

img:nth-child(2) {
  filter: contrast(0) sepia(100%);
}

img:nth-child(3) {
  filter: contrast(0) sepia(100%) saturate(1000%);
}

img:nth-child(4) {
  filter: contrast(0) sepia(100%) saturate(1000%) hue-rotate(320deg);
}

img:hover {
  filter: none;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhNE1.png">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhNE1.png">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhNE1.png">
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhNE1.png">
```