# How to Layer image on top of another to show different variant of a product?

Tags: javascript, image, multi-layer

I'm working on an e-commerce web site. It has few products with multiple color variants. Each product has 3 options that can each have 3 different colours. For example:

Product 1 -> Option 2 -> Red

or

Product 1 -> Option 1 -> Black

Upon selecting the colour choice the product image needs to change to this colour to reflect the change.

Obviously, this could be achieved using multiple images. The only problem I have here is the sheer amount of images I would have to create, one for each possible combination.

I would prefer something which would simply layer the option on top of a base image.

Any ideas on updating colour options on an image without creating individual images for each option?

Comment: Manipulate the pixels on a canvas element. Convert from RGB to HSV and back to preserve texture and shadows.

Comment: @GetSet could you please explain a bit more. I am new to canvas.

Comment: HTML5 Canvas -- there are tutorials online. It wont magically solve this problem however. What you really need is an algorithm. My previous comment touches on the gist of the concept. Work in HSV color space so that you can adjust color without losing texture and shadows. You'll also need a mask of some sort to only the affect the desired pixels.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might give you a place to start:

```js
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document);

$('.row').addEventListener('mouseover', hdl_mousein);

function hdl_mousein(e){
  if (e.target.classList.contains('btn') ){
    const col = e.target.getAttribute('data-color');
    const img = e.target.closest('.card').querySelector('img');
    if (col == 'red'){
      img.classList.remove('imgGreen');
      img.classList.add('imgRed');
    } else {
      img.classList.remove('imgRed');
      img.classList.add('imgGreen');
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.row {display:flex;}

.card{padding:20px 40px;margin-right:20px;}

.btnRow{display:flex;}
.btn {padding:10px 20px;margin-right:10px;border:1px solid grey;border-radius:4px;cursor:pointer;}

.imgRed{filter: grayscale(100%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(240deg);}
.imgGreen{filter: grayscale(100%) sepia(100%) hue-rotate(90deg);}
```

```html
<div class="row">


  <div class="card">
    <div class="imgBland"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/100" /></div>
    <div class="btnRow">
      <div class="btn" data-color="red">Red</div>
      <div class="btn" data-color="green">Green</div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- .card -->

  <div class="card">
    <div class="imgBland"><img src="https://picsum.photos/220/100" /></div>
    <div class="btnRow">
      <div class="btn" data-color="red">Red</div>
      <div class="btn" data-color="green">Green</div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- .card -->


</div><!-- .row -->
```

#### Reference:

[css filter to make elements one color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999597/css-filter-to-make-elements-one-color)

Comment: I do not want to change color using color code. I want to layer/overlay/top an image with another image

Comment: Basically by example: a photo of a model wearing a shirt; and the color of the shirt can be changed based on whats available).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to colorize just a portion of an image - I am not familiar with the use of canvas in this use case. I have no idea how you would identify the area to be changed from product to product... My gut feeling is that individual photos would be easier.